# What CMake variable is used to set C++ Standard Library in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, c++11, cmake

I have a pure C++11 DLL (No dependencies of any kind) I have been able to compile on Linux and Windows for some time now using CMake to generate the project files and make/MSVC to compile in each respective native system.

I want to compile on OSX now and I have been having a lot of problems getting CMake to set the correct project settings in XCode to compile the DLL.

Software versions:

```
XCode v5.0
CMake v2.8.12
```

The relevant CMake script code:

```
# Set output directory if Apple OSX:
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    message("CMAKE HAS DETECTED A OSX SYSTEM - BUILDING FOR XCODE!")

    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_VERSION "com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0")
    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD "c++0x")
    set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY "libc++")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++")

    IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
        SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/OSX/Release)
    ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
    IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
        SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/OSX/Debug)
    ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
```

However the settings do not correctly come through into the XCode project file:

[image]

You can see that the CMake commands make their way into the 'Other C++ Flags' area. But XCode will still fail to compile. However, if I change the 'C++ Standard Library' variable to 'libc++' it will compile fine.

Note: I could post the compile error logs however I think that the above correctly identifies the root cause - I just need to know what CMake command actually sets the correct XCode property above.

Comment: Probably you have already looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879630/using-c0x-in-xcode-4-2-project-via-cmake . Anyway, it looks that xcode in the newer version with Maverks turns on C++11 by default.

Comment: Yep. Doesn't help sadly.

Answer (score 9):

For a minimal test project the following does the job:

```
SET(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY "libc++")
```

Maybe it's interfering with the following line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++")
```

Also one remark on this line, is there the `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}` on intention, or did you really mean `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}`?

Comment: I've tried disabling all other related SET functions to no avail. Can you confirm what version of CMake and XCode you're running? I'm running CMake v2.8.12 and XCode v5.0.

Answer (score 5):

you can use set_property

```
macro (set_xcode_property TARGET XCODE_PROPERTY XCODE_VALUE)
set_property (TARGET ${TARGET} PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_${XCODE_PROPERTY}
    ${XCODE_VALUE})
endmacro (set_xcode_property)

set_xcode_property(${your_target_name} CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD "c++0x")
set_xcode_property(${your_target_name} CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY "libc++")
```

Comment: Hrm. I'll definitely give this go very soon. Could you provide a little info on where set_property() is documented and why one would use it instead of just set()?

Comment: Why we just can not do this?

`set_property(TARGET ${your_target_name} PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD "c++0x")
set_property(TARGET ${your_target_name} PROPERTY XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY "libc++")`