# Building c++ project on Windows with CMake, Clang and Ninja

Tags: c++, windows, build, clang, ninja

I currently have cmake, clang and ninja installed on windows. I am trying to use CMake to generate a ninja build file to compile a very simple hello world program.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test_project)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

`main.cpp` is a simple hello world program.

On the command line I run this: `cmake -G Ninja ..` and I get the following errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.5.0
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/nologo'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/showIncludes'
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.5.0
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/nologo'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/showIncludes'
-- Check for working C compiler using: Ninja
-- Check for working C compiler using: Ninja -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/llvm_build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clang.exe" is
  not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTryCompileExec375034429

  [1/2] Building C object
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec375034429.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj


  [2/2] Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec375034429.exe


  FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd .  &&
  C:\llvm_build\RelWithDebInfo\bin\clang.exe
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec375034429.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -o
  cmTryCompileExec375034429.exe && cd .


  clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable



  clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
  invocation)



  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The `CMakeError.log` file looks like this:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/llvm_build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clang.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: C:/llvm_build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clang++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
clang++.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTryCompileExec2120850158
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2120850158.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2120850158.exe

FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd . && C:\llvm_build\RelWithDebInfo\bin\clang.exe     CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2120850158.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  -o cmTryCompileExec2120850158.exe   && cd .

clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable


clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It appears that cmake is trying to test clang with windows options `/nologo` and `/showIncludes`. I cannot figure out how to tell cmake to pass the proper arguments.

FWIW I'm running 64bit Windows 7

**EDIT:**

So I looked through the built in cmake files and I found that the `CMakeClDeps.cmake` file was the culprit for adding the `/nologo /showIncludes` options. It appears that if I set Clang as the compiler then cmake thinks that visual studio is the compiler (it sets MSVC_C_ARCHITECTURE_ID to x86).

I removed the line in `CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake` that sets `MSVC_C_ARCHITECTURE_ID` and after trying again I get the following errors:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Ninja
-- Check for working C compiler using: Ninja -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/llvm_build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clang.exe" is
  not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:C:/ninja/ninja.exe cmTryCompileExec2815594422

  [1/2] Building C object
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2815594422.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj


  [2/2] Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2815594422.exe


  FAILED: cmd.exe /c cd .  &&
  C:\llvm_build\RelWithDebInfo\bin\clang.exe
  CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2815594422.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -o
  cmTryCompileExec2815594422.exe && cd .


  clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable



  clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
  invocation)



  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/test_proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Can you try, near the beginning of your cmake file, to write: `remove_definitions( /nologo )` and `remove_definitions( /showIncludes )`? It might work, but in case it does, it's a nice little workaround.

Comment: Otherwise, you can look through CMakeCCompilerId.c and CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp and see if something's wrong.

Comment: @Shingetsu Removing the definitions did not change anything and I didn't find anything by looking through those files. But, I did find where the /nologo /showIncludes options were coming from and edited my question.

Comment: Check if that same file sets any other MSVC options, and replace them with clang.
Do note that CMake does not natively support clang (yet).
You can try manually overriding 90% of the required options as shown in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if it can be helpful but I had the same error. Now I can compile with clang(3.7.1)/ninja(1.6)/cmake(3.4.1) on Windows performing the following actions in a build directory:

1. load the relevant vcvarsXX.bat file (e.g. `"<Your Visual Studio location>\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86`)
2. set both CC and CXX to `clang-cl` (instead of `clang` and `clang++`)
3. run `cmake -G Ninja <project>`
4. run `cmake --build .`

Comment: Do you know if the compile_commands.json file that is generated with this setup can be fed to the clang-tidy tool or does the clan-tidy tool expect the command line arguments of the clang.exe ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the second set of errors I received were because clang could not find the linker. I had built clang using visual studio but at the time it couldn't find the visual studio linker. All I had to do was run it in the visual studio development console.

CMake still thinks that clang is a visual studio compiler so in the `CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake` file there is a line that looks like this:

`set(MSVC_${lang}_ARCHITECTURE_ID "${ARCHITECTURE_ID}")`

and I changed it to look like this

```
if (COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  set(MSVC_${lang}_ARCHITECTURE_ID "${ARCHITECTURE_ID}")
endif()
```

Hopefully this doesn't break any other CMake functionality.

Comment: I am still having issues - I didn't have the issue with it being detected as MSVC. I've set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID=Clang but somehow it fails in a similar fashion to your last errors.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on CMake 3.6.1.  I still get the /nologo etc flags that cause a failure compiling the test program.  I see that CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID (in CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake) always sets the parent scope MSVC_${lang}_ARCHITECTURE_ID and tried only setting that if it is set in the local scope, but then I get CMAKE_RC_COMPILER not set.