# Compiling Elmer FEM on macOS Mojave causes the fatal error: 'string.h' file not found

Tags: macos, cmake, compiler-errors

I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://www.csc.fi/web/elmer/sources-and-compilation) to compile [Elmer FEM](http://www.elmerfem.org/blog/) on macOS Mojave `Version 10.14.6`. However, when running the `make install` I get the error message:

```
.../elmerfem/umfpack/src/umfpack/include/umf_internal.h:29:10: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include <string.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [umfpack/src/umfpack/umfpack_zl_save_symbolic.c] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file `umfpack/src/umfpack/umfpack_zl_save_symbolic.c'
make[1]: *** [umfpack/src/umfpack/CMakeFiles/umfpack.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

searching the internet [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26185979/4999991) suggests

- `xcode-select --install`
- `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`

which had already been done before in my case and have no effect on the above error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55465527/4999991) and [this](https://donatstudios.com/MojaveMissingHeaderFiles) post suggest

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target / -allowUntrusted
```

which leads to the error message

> installer: The install failed (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.)

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it. Thanks for your kind support in advance.

**P.S.1.** As was asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/ffbbnt/compiling_elmer_fem_on_macos_mojave_causes_the/fjxkkko?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), my `make` version is `GNU Make 3.81`.

**P.S.2.** the list of `string.h` files on my hard drive [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/ffbbnt/compiling_elmer_fem_on_macos_mojave_causes_the/fjxy93z?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

**P.S.3.** the output of CMake is pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/izFiPXFV).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I solved the problem. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380618/4999991), I ran

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++ ..
```

while being inside the `build` folder. and then `make .` worked fine except some warning. I'm still not sure what was the problem or if this is the optimal/canonical solution. So I will not mark this as the accepted solution until others provide better ones.

**P.S.1.** I sent a pull request [here](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/homebrew-elmerfem/pull/14) on Elmer's HomeBrew formula as well.

**P.S.2.** To compile with OpenMP and MPI:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/bin/gcc-9 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/bin/g++-9 -DWITH_Mumps=FALSE -DWITH_MPI=TRUE -DWITH_OpenMP=TRUE -DWITH_MKL=FALSE -DWITH_ELMERGUI=TRUE -DWITH_ELMERPOST=FALSE -DWITH_ELMERGUITESTER=FALSE ..
```

I have GNU GCC and OpenMPI installed via HomeBrew `brew install gcc open-mpi`.

**P.S.3.** If you want the ElmerGUI also installed:

1. install qt4 with `brew install cartr/qt4/qt@4` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50442031/4999991)
2. install qwt with `brew install cartr/qt4/qwt-qt4`
3. then `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/bin/gcc-9 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_3/bin/g++-9 -DWITH_Mumps=FALSE -DWITH_MPI=TRUE -DWITH_OpenMP=TRUE -DWITH_MKL=FALSE -DWITH_ELMERGUI=TRUE -DWITH_ELMERPOST=TRUE -DWITH_ELMERGUITESTER=TRUE -DQWT_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/qwt-qt4/6.1.3_1/lib/qwt.framework/Versions/6/Headers/  ..`