# Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-optimization

I would like to change the default values for `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` in CMake. Basically, I have some project defaults that differ just slightly from CMake's (for release, for instance), and I shouldn't have to ask myself "Oh, does their -O3 or our -O2 take precedence when added with add_compile_options."

Now, I know how to set these values, but I don't know how to make them user editable in the two usual ways: by using -`DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=yourflags` on the command line or by configuring it with ccmake or CMakeSetup.

The problem being that CMAKE sets and caches its own defaults for these, and if you try to overwrite the variables without using FORCE, the "defaults" are never changed. If I use FORCE in my set command: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG blah CACHE STRING "" FORCE)`, it will overwrite it every time the script is run, eliminating the possibility for the user to change it if he wishes.

I managed to hack it to work with CCMAKE by doing the following, but this still doesn't work with `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` as it overwrites the user change AFTER he's done it:

```
set(DEFAULTS_SET FALSE CACHE BOOL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-this -that" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(DEFAULTS_SET TRUE CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

Obviously, this is a nasty hack and doesn't completely work(in the case of cmake -Dwhatever=thisorthat). I could add other build types as well, but I don't really see why that should be necessary just to change a few simple things.

**Edit March 1st, 2015:**

I've created a solution that works, though I still am not super thrilled about what I have to do. I'd seen other comments that solve the problem of setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and friends without having them get clobbered, but this originally didn't work for me because I was trying to also select them based on the compiler that was in use. The compiler isn't determined, however, until it has already filled the variables for me. The trick I used is as follows. You must set the flags variables to something 'special' before the project command.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "_UNSET" CACHE STRING "")
project(your_project C CXX)

if(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} STREQUAL "_UNSET")
    # Do some compiler switching here and then set your flags with FORCE.
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-ggdb3 -O0" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
endif()
```

This now allows me to choose defaults that are completely override-able via command line with -D or in cmake-gui.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just wanted to add the four possibilities I see:

1. Having your own toolchain files containing the presets for each compiler you support like:

   **GNUToolchain.cmake**

   ```
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-ggdb3 -O0" CACHE STRING "")
   ```

   And then use it with

   ```
    cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:string=GNUToolchain.cmake ...
   ```
2. You can try to determine the compiler by checking [`CMAKE_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html) (which is valid before the [`project()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/project.html) command):

   **CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
    if("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES "Makefiles" OR 
       ("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES "Ninja" AND NOT WIN32))
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-ggdb3 -O0" CACHE STRING "")
    endif()

    project(your_project C CXX)
   ```
3. You can use [`CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE.html) to give a script with your own `..._INIT` values:

   > It is loaded after CMake’s builtin compiler and platform information modules have been loaded but before the information is used. The file may set platform information variables to override CMake’s defaults.

   **MyInitFlags.cmake**

   ```
    # Overwrite the init values choosen by CMake
    if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-ggdb3 -O0")
    endif()
   ```

   **CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
    set(CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE "MyInitFlags.cmake")

    project(your_project C CXX)
   ```
4. You can simplify your solution from March 1st by checking against the `..._INIT` variants of the compiler flag variables:

   **CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
    project(your_project C CXX)

    if (DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT AND  
        "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
        # Overwrite the init values choosen by CMake
        if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
            set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-ggdb3 -O0" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
        endif()
    endif()
   ```

*Comments*:

I prefer and use the toolchain variant. But I admit it has the disadvantage of having to give the toolchain file manually (if you are not calling `cmake` via a script/batch file).

*References*:

- [CMake: In which order are files parsed (cache, toolchain, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)
- [cmake - Global linker flag setting (for all targets in directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698580/cmake-global-linker-flag-setting-for-all-targets-in-directory)
- [Switching between GCC and Clang/LLVM using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake)

Comment: You can concat new rules to previous rules, ex: `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")`

Comment: Option 3 seems like the "most correct" way to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Florian's answer using toolchain files is a good one for earlier versions of CMake. But CMake 3.19 added a feature called [*presets*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) that helps manage common sets of cache variables for your project. Basically, you create at least one of two files, `CMakePresets.json` and `CMakeUserPresets.json` (usually added to `.gitignore` or similar), that contain specifications of how to configure the project.

For example, you might write:

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 19,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "displayName": "Default",
      "description": "Build using Ninja and a GCC-like compiler",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG": "-ggdb3 -O0"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "default-vcpkg",
      "displayName": "Default (vcpkg)",
      "description": "Default build with vcpkg (from VCPKG_ROOT)",
      "inherits": "default",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, from the source directory, your CMake command line would just become:

```shell
$ cmake --preset=default
```

This approach has a few advantages:

1. It makes the command line a *lot* simpler
2. It's compatible with other toolchain files (like vcpkg's in the second preset)
3. It can override flags that are usually unconditionally added to the `*_INIT` flags.
4. You don't have to write awkward logic in your CMakeLists.txt.
5. Presets are opt-in for the user, which is important if you're distributing a library.

Expanding on points 4 and 5: it is a bad idea to add flags unless they absolutely *must* be there to compile correctly *and* there isn't a built-in feature for reaching those flags (eg. `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`). If someone tries to compile your library with a different compiler (or even a different version of the same compiler) they could run into issues if, for example, you add a warning flag that's too new or not supported. You can work around this with generator expressions and/or complex logic (like the `_UNDEF` trick above), but it's generally just easier and more convenient to use a toolchain or these new presets.

For instance, to correctly add `-Wsuggest-override`, you would need to write:

```cmake
target_compile_options(lib PRIVATE $<$<AND:$<VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL:$<CXX_COMPILER_VERSION>,5.1>,$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GNU>>:-Wsuggest-override>)

# ... or ...

# Note: only correct if using "PRIVATE". Must use a genex for INTERFACE/PUBLIC because the whole genex gets exported, whereas this flag will get exported verbatim.
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU" AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 5.1)
  target_compile_options(lib PRIVATE -Wsuggest-override)
endif ()
```

Or you could just put the flag in a toolchain/preset where you already know what compiler you're using.