# How to configure cmake in a way that it generates Visual Studio 2013+ project files with /MP option

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake

I have a cmake project with many cpp files (around 400+) and using /MP (multithreaded) compiler option speeds up the compilation significantly on CPU's with many cores.

The problem is, that everytime I regenerate the solution files using CMake, the option is disabled, resulting in compilation being very slow. I can fix that by changing option of EVERY single project (solution consist of many various projects) by hand inside of Visual Studio. However, everytime I regenerate the solution files by running CMake (for example when I git pull someone else's changes which added / removed some files) this change gets overwritten.

How can I make it persistent so that CMake always enable multithreaded compilation inside of VS projects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the following [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_compile_options) at the top of your project's main `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
add_compile_options($<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/MP>)
```

or with older CMake versions < 2.8.12:

```
project(...)
if (MSVC)
    add_definitions("/MP")
endif()
```

If you can't or don't want to change the main `CMakeLists.txt` file, you could always add your flags manually to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` cached variable e.g. by using [CMake's GUI](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-gui.1.html) (assuming that your CMake project itself is not forcing the values of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`).

**References**

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)
- [Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)

Comment: Which version introduced this option? I am now getting errors on debian like "unknown option add_compile_options" with ancient CMake version. Is it possible to wrap it somehow so that it's ignored on old cmake versions?

Comment: @Petr If you want to support older versions also, I would recommend to not take `add_compile_options()` but a command that even older versions do understand. I've updated the answer accordingly.