# CMake AMRCC + custom linker

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, linker-flags

I'm trying to use `cmake` in a project which is compiled using `armcc`, but use a custom proprietary linker (not `armlink`).

I've changed the variables in the `toolchain.cmake` file as following:

```
unset (CMAKE_LINKER CACHE)
set (CMAKE_LINKER "my_linker" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

unset (CMAKE_ARMCC_LINKER CACHE)
set (CMAKE_ARMCC_LINKER "my_linker" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

unset (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS CACHE )
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-flag1 -flag2" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

unset (CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
set (CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> -o <TARGET>")

unset (CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
set (CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> -o <TARGET>")
```

But when `cmake` tries to check my compiler suite, it fails in the linking step:

```
-- Check for working C compiler: armcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "armcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

... (compiling commands that worked hidden here)

Linking C executable cmTC_c08ef.elf

"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_c08ef.dir\link.txt --verbose=1

my_linker -flag1 -flag2 CMakeFiles/cmTC_c08ef.dir/testCCompiler.o -o cmTC_c08ef.elf --list cmTC_c08ef.map
```

The problem is the `--list cmTC_c08ef.map` at the end of command line (which does not exist in the `toolchain.cmake` file).

In order to make it work, I need to change the file `<cmake_install_dir>\Modules\Compiler\ARMCC.cmake` as following:

```
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_LINK_EXECUTABLE      "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_${lang}_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> --list <TARGET_BASE>.map")
#  set(CMAKE_${lang}_LINK_EXECUTABLE      "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_${lang}_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET>")
```

There is a better approach to solve this issue or it is the only way?

Edit: Apparently this is a bug in the cmake's armcc support, so I will keep my change in the ARMCC.cmake file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the cmake's armcc support, so I will keep my change in the ARMCC.cmake file.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly the use case of a relatively new ([version 3.6](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/release/3.6.html#id5)) global CMake variable named [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html). So just add the following to your toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

---

**Edit**: If your custom linker also gives you trouble outside the compiler check, simply split your toolchain into 2 files (`toolchain.cmake` to be read before and `makerules.cmake` after the CMake's compiler detection):

**toolchain.cmake**

```
[...]
set (CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}/makerules.cmake")
```

**makerules.cmake**

```
set (CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> -o <TARGET>")
set (CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE "<CMAKE_LINKER> <CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> -o <TARGET>")
```

---

**Refrences**

- [`CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html)
- [Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake)
- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Florian. This way the the check step works, but when I try to link my application the "--list <TARGET_BASE>.map" still here (ignoring the override of the CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE variable) .

Comment: @Valmir The toolchain is loaded before everything else (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631)). If you want to change normal variables after the CMake compiler detection you need another script to be given via [`CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_USER_MAKE_RULES_OVERRIDE.html) (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209)). You shouldn't normally need to move your `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` settings from your toolchain to such a separate file. I consider those variables being none-cached a bug in the ARMCC support.

Comment: Thanks again @Florian. Unfortunately I will keep my change in ARMCC.cmake in order to keep my project working.