# How to partially disabling cmake C/C++ custom compiler checking

Tags: c++, c, compilation, cmake

I am trying to do some crosscompilation using cmake. Some are easy with all the examples on Internet, I managed to crosscompile my library on Linux (x86 and ARM), Windows and Android. But now I would like to do it on a custom platform.

The process I need to achieve:

1. Sourcing my environment (this destroy all previous bash classic environment)
2. Compile with cmake
3. Execute what I want

But Cmake is testing for symbols in my custom C/C++ libraries which make my library unable to compile. The errors I have are that cmake some versions of GLIBCXX and CXXABI (no C issues) but not all of them.

Is there a way to make cmake ok with it ?

EDIT:

I tried using:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
```

And with:

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
...
cmake_force_c_compiler(${ENV_PATH}/bin/${CC})
cmake_force_cxx_compiler(${ENV_PATH}/bin/${CXX})
```

But cmake is still checking for symbols.

Comment: try get latest CMake, it has a lot improvements for cross-compiling since version 3.5

Answer (score 6):

Without having your environment nor the error message it's not easy to tell the actual root cause but here are two of the common causes and respective fixes:

1. If you don't have a complete [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) created for your custom environment - so CMake can't link a simple test program - you can try the relatively new (version 3.6) global CMake variable named [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html).

   So just add the following:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
   ```

   Then CMake would just try to build a static library.
2. To have only the most common GCC compiler variables set and have only some basic checks, try:

   ```
   SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
   ```

   See [CMake Cross Compiling: Setting up the system and toolchain](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#Setting_up_the_system_and_toolchain):

   > If your target is an embedded system without OS set CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME to "Generic"

**References**

- [CMake AMRCC + custom linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359796/cmake-amrcc-custom-linker)
- [cmake cross-compile with specific linker doesn't pass arguments to armlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313387/cmake-cross-compile-with-specific-linker-doesnt-pass-arguments-to-armlink)

Answer (score 5):

Commandline:

```
    cmake ... \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED=TRUE \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED=TRUE
```

or

CMakeLists.txt

```
    ...
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
    ...
```

Works for me.