# cmake: CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS and flags that start with "/D"

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a library with CMake. The target platform is non-standard. The library several `try_compile` commands. In particular, the ones inside CheckTypeSize.cmake are failing. To have the compilation succeed, I need to change the flags and link libraries that those `try_compile` command uses (and I do not want to modify the CMake installation). It seems as though the (undocumented) `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES` and `CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS` are used within that module. In the toolchain file, I do:

```
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "/DLL")
```

Unfortunately, I want to set a flag that starts with `/D` (in this case `/DLL`). When I do this, the variable gets translated into `/D LL`. Is there any way to indicate to CMake that the string shouldn't be parsed into a compile define?

Comment: Show us some minimal code, what module are you using that has undocumented stuff?

Comment: well, I just mean that CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS isn't documented, in the public documentation, only at the start of those cmake (internal) module files.

Comment: My recommendation would be to update to CMake 3.6 and add `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)`. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700198/how-to-partially-disabling-cmake-c-c-custom-compiler-checking) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931068/tell-cmake-to-use-c-compiler-for-c-files-coming-from-cmake).

Comment: @Florian - solves my problem - add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Please don't use internal CMake commands. My recommendation in your case - `try_compile` not working in cross-compiling environment and the linker is throwing errors - is to update to CMake 3.6 and add

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Then CMake's `try_compile` will only try static library linking (and not an executable).

**References**

- [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html)
- [How to partially disabling cmake C/C++ custom compiler checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700198/how-to-partially-disabling-cmake-c-c-custom-compiler-checking)
- [Tell CMake to use C++ compiler for C files coming from CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931068/tell-cmake-to-use-c-compiler-for-c-files-coming-from-cmake)