# How to Add Linux Compilation to Cmake Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Visual Studio has added lots of new features for C++ in the past year.

**CMake**
With the CMake support, I can do "Open Folder" and select a folder with a CMakeLists.txt file in it. Visual Studio does a lot of nice work in discovering and building it automatically.

**Linux Compilation**
Visual studio now supports remote compilation on Linux over SSH. Several tutorials show how users can create a new "Linux Console Application" in Visual Studio, and it will automatically ask to setup an SSH connection to be used for building it. I don't see any instructions for how to do this on an existing project of any kind.

Particularly with a CMake project, is it possible to open a CMake folder in Visual Studio 2017 and have it built over on a remote Linux machine?  IfSoHow?

Comment: Please note, I have looked at this similar post, and the answer is not satisfactory:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762424/cmake-generator-for-visual-studio-linux-cross-platform

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no build-in support for a VS "Linux Console Application" in CMake yet (as for CMake version 3.9).

**Edit:** Visual Studio 2017 15.4 now comes with something similar without generating actual `.vcxproj` files. See [Visual C++ for Linux Development with CMake](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/25/visual-c-for-linux-development-with-cmake/)

With a standard CMake version besides the possibilities described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762424/cmake-generator-for-visual-studio-linux-cross-platform) using existing `.vcxproj` files as a template, you can only trick CMake into generating those project types:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(HelloLinux)

file(WRITE main.cpp [=[
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from Linux Console!" << std::endl;
}
]=])

add_executable(HelloLinux "main.cpp")

set_target_properties(
    HelloLinux
    PROPERTIES
        VS_GLOBAL_KEYWORD "Linux"
        VS_GLOBAL_ApplicationType "Linux"
        VS_GLOBAL_ApplicationTypeRevision "1.0"
        VS_GLOBAL_TargetLinuxPlatform "Generic"
        VS_GLOBAL_LinuxProjectType "{D51BCBC9-82E9-4017-911E-C93873C4EA2B}"
)
```

This actually works and produces a Linux `.vcxproj` project that is accepted by VS. But since we sidestepped CMake here, none of the other compiler/linker options you define in your CMake script will be assigned.

So my recommendation is to [raise a feature request](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues) for CMake itself to directly support this (e.g. via platform toolset option `Remote_GCC_1_0`).

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to work as you expect, yet. It seems you need to create separate linux vcproject for your existing cmake codebase. There is nothing like linux target in VS options. For more information see comments in this [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/).

You may either create 'new linux project' and copy your sources or try (and adapt) using for existing sources these unofficial scripts: 
https://github.com/robotdad/vclinux