# How can cmake add custom entry in a project's vcxproj PropertyGroup?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I am using cmake to generate a Windows/VisualStudio solution of a multi-platform C++ project.

There is a specific entry (a simple path to a folder data) in project's properties that I would like cmake to fill in for me. This entry is added by an external plug-in I cannot modify.

Filling the option in VS project properties adds the following entry in the `MyAppExecutable.vcxproj` file :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|PLATFORM'">
  <AppDataFolder>D:\myappdata</AppDataFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I would like cmake to add this `AppDataFolder` value for me.

It would be even better if it could set it at once for all possible `PLATFORM`, and whether compiling in `Release`, `Debug` or whatever else. Hopefully adding it inside `<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">` would achieve this objective ?

Is there a way to make cmake set this value inside the project's file ?

Comment: You can try `set_target_properties(MyAppExecutable PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_AppDataFolder "D:\\myappdata")`

Comment: I tried it and it works ! Thanks for the suggestion. Can you make an answer, so that I can select it as the solution ?

Comment: You're welcome. Put my comment into an answer. I think you can even use `$<SHELL_PATH:...>` generator expression if the path is known to CMake (to avoid manually converting to backslashes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

For setting a global VS project property you can use the [`VS_GLOBAL_<variable>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_GLOBAL_variable.html) target property:

```
set_target_properties(MyAppExecutable PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_AppDataFolder "D:\\myappdata")
```

**Reference**

- [How to Add Linux Compilation to Cmake Project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468507/how-to-add-linux-compilation-to-cmake-project-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I think this will put the the tag in the non config specific <PropertyGroup>. Do you know if there is a way to put it in the <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|PLATFORM'"> tag?

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing it could be to generate a PowerShell script and make cmake call it at the end of the generation process.

Here is an example of PowerShell script I have written :

```
$myvcxprojpath = 'D:\build\myapp\PLATFORM\MyAppExecutable.vcxproj'
$mydatapath = 'D:\myappdata'

[xml]$xml = (Get-Content $myvcxprojpath)
$globalpropgroup = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup | where {$_.Label -eq 'Globals'}
$datapath = $globalpropgroup.AppDataFolder
if ($datapath -eq $null)
{
    $newNode = $xml.CreateElement("AppDataFolder")
    $newNode.set_InnerXML($mydatapath)
    $globalpropgroup.AppendChild($newNode)
}
else
{
    $globalpropgroup.AppDataFolder= $mydatapath
}
$xml = [xml]$xml.OuterXml.Replace(" xmlns=`"`"", "")
$xml.Save($myvcxprojpath)
```

This script looks for the AppDataFolder entry. If it is not present it creates one ; in the other case it simply updates its content.

I had to add a line to remove the empty `xmlns` label in the new xml node.