# Building with CMake, Ninja and Clang on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, clang, ninja

**This question is from 2017 and probably outdated. Please take the provided instructions with a pinch of salt since better solutions might be available now.**

---

Dear fellow C++ coders,

after using the Visual Studio toolchain for building on windows for a while, I decided to give Clang 5 a shot.

I installed the LLVM 5.0.0 binaries, the Ninja build environment, the VS 2017 Tools and CMake 3.9.3. The final aim is to be able to compile C and C++ applications for Windows using VS Code with the CMake integration as "IDE" and Clang with LLD as compiler and linker.

The compilation and execution of a simple program worked perfectly fine ([screenshot of the respective terminal history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJXn0.png)). Clang automatically detected the standard lib for Windows within the VS Tools directories and produced an executable output.

The next step was setting up a simple build with Ninja ([screenshot of ninja.build file and terminal history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Ymk.png)). The build process worked as expected and produced a working executable, just like before.

The problems begun when I started to integrate CMake into the process. My expectation is that CMake produces a ninja build file and runs it, correct?
I tried the following CMakeLists file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(Test)

add_executable(Test main.c)
```

and called CMake with `cmake -G Ninja`.
The resulting output was disappointing and I don't understand enough to figure out respectively solve the problem myself.

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Meine_Programme/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Meine_Programme/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Meine_Programme/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Meine_Programme/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: D:/Dateien/Downloads/Test/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  

  Run Build Command:"C:/Meine_Programme/Ninja_Build/ninja.exe" "cmTC_eeb5c"

  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_eeb5c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj

  FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_eeb5c.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj 

  C:\Meine_Programme\LLVM\bin\clang.exe /nologo /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /MDd
  /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 /showIncludes
  /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_eeb5c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
  /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_eeb5c.dir\ -c testCCompiler.c

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/nologo'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/DWIN32'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/D_WINDOWS'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/W3'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/MDd'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/Zi'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/Ob0'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/Od'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/RTC1'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '/showIncludes'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory:
  '/FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_eeb5c.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj'

  clang.exe: error: no such file or directory:
  '/FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_eeb5c.dir\'

  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Dateien/Downloads/Test/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Dateien/Downloads/Test/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I guess that the problem is related to CMake calling clang with VS style options using slash instead of preceded by minus, like clang requires.

Thanks for helping me out guys, I appreciate it :-)

Just leave me a comment if you require further information.

**Answer to Florians post**

I tried Florians command but omitted the path to ninja for a shorter notation and it turned out to work just fine.

```
cmake -E env LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld"  cmake -H. -G Ninja -Bbuild -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH="C:\MeineProgramme\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH="C:\MeineProgramme\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID="Clang" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID="Clang" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Generic"
```

CMake produced a ninja build file.

I ran `ninja all` to build the executable as `Test`. I renamed it to `Test.exe` and the program executed happily. So far... success!!! But much more complicated than I expected.

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38174328/2436175

Comment: @Antonio Thanks for your reply but it looks like CMake is not able to specify a toolset for Ninja. I tried `cmake -G Ninja -T LLVM-VS2017` but it told me, that the specification of a toolset is not supported for the respective generator, to bad :-(I wouldn't been surprised if it worked because, as mentioned above, I actually do have all required tools installed except VS Studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a way to use my favoured tools in a way that pleases me. It's not perfect, but it works better than Florians approach with setting the system name to *Generic* (which I've been using for some time now)

I first set up VS Code to use the VS developers terminal as its standard terminal. I did this by adding the following line to the VS Code preferences

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\MeineProgramme\\Visual_Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\LaunchDevCmd.bat"
```

After starting the terminal within VS Code I need to call the respective batch file which sets the required environment variables (in my case `vcvars64.bat`). These can be found in

```
C:\MeineProgramme\Visual_Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build
```

After navigating to my build directory I run CMake with the following options

```
cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH="C:\MeineProgramme\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe" -DCMAKE_LINKER:PATH="C:\MeineProgramme\LLVM\bin\lld-link.exe"
```

this encourages CMake to use all my installed LLVM tools. Not only `clang` and `lld` (make sure to use lld-link which supports the options led by a `/`), but also `llvm-ar` and `llvm-ranlib`. The only MS build tool used is the resource compiler which I don't use at the moment.

So far success I think.

Don't hesitate to contact me or comment below if you got further questions.

Comment: You could probably also use the `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017` shortcut located at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools\VC`. This would call the `vcvars64.bat` for you automatically.

Comment: What are the variables needed for Ninja for that? I want to be able to imitate this on my own `cmd` window.

Comment: @Royi I'm don't understand. What do you mean? This works with normal cmd but you either have to have `Visual_Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build` on the path or reference `vcvars64.bat` with the full path. The call to cmake is the same in every environment.

Comment: You say `this encourages CMake to use all my installed LLVM tools.`. Namely some System Environment Settings which were set in `vcvars64.bat` made that happen. I asked if you specifically which ones (Because it adds many).

Comment: Huh, I got no clue but LLVM needs the include and library variables set to be able to find the required files during build. Why don't you just execute the environment script?

Answer (score 17):

Inspired by the ["Ways to Compile with Clang on Windows"](https://metricpanda.com/rival-fortress-update-27-compiling-with-clang-on-windows) blog post from @Unspongeful and after some extended testing, the following command line worked for me (and yes, it's one big command I just splitted into several lines for better readability):

```bsh
> cmake -E env LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld-link" PATH="<path\to\ninja>" 
      cmake -H. -G Ninja -Bbuild 
         -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" 
         -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" 
         -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID="Clang" 
         -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID="Clang" 
         -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Generic"
```

Here is some background information:

- I injected your linker flags with the `LDFLAGS` environment variable

  See [Passing compiler options cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284275/passing-compiler-options-cmake)
- I reduced the `PATH` environment variable to just point to where `ninja` is located, because CMake was picking my `MinGW` toolchain (which I didn't want included in the build process)

  Related to [Environment variable used by CMake to detect Visual C++ compiler tools for Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069632/environment-variable-used-by-cmake-to-detect-visual-c-compiler-tools-for-ninja)
- Defining the compiler ids "bypasses the check for working compiler and basic compiler information tests"

  See obsolete, but sometimes useful [`CMakeForceCompiler` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CMakeForceCompiler.html)
- And I set [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html) to `Generic` to avoid having any additional platform specific compiler/linker flags added by CMake

  See [How to partially disabling cmake C/C++ custom compiler checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700198/how-to-partially-disabling-cmake-c-c-custom-compiler-checking)

It seems at the moment you have to bypass a lot of CMake's automatic checks to get it working. So probably check with the CMake team or [raise an issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues) to get this scenario officially supported.

And the last part with a `Generic` system is probably not the best choice, because it will skip Windows specific settings like the `.exe` suffix.

But it was the only constellation that actually worked:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: build
```

Comment: Huh... that is a much longer command than I expected. Let me try your suggestion and I will report back. Thank you much for your extensive research man.

Comment: @Simon You are welcome. And yes, probably it's better/easier to put all this into a CMake toolchain file. If you have verified the above command line, I can add a toolchain approach for easier handling (like in [this blog post](http://mhungerford.blogspot.de/2010/10/cmake-and-clangllvm-fun.html) from @MatthewHungerford).

Comment: I started an issue on CMakes Gitlab. If you'd like to have a look... https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17329#

Comment: I updated my question with an answer to your post. Can you provide me with additional information i.e. a single CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @Simon I'll add some more information during the next days. Just one thing about the path to `ninja`. Since it's the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) we are overwriting it would in your case just be `PATH="C:\MeineProgramme\Ninja\bin"` (without the executable).

Comment: Oops, my bad :-/ well... it turned out to be just fine ;-)

Comment: There is an open issue with CMake to add support for Clang (not just Clang-cl) on Windows: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16439

Comment: Setting the `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_ID` flags manually is not a good idea. You end up skipping CMake's other compiler extraction logic (such as compiler versions which ends up making checks for C++ language level support (e.g., `-std=c++17`) fail.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into similar problems when trying to use clang cmake and msvc 2017 together. At least for a very simple test project, I was able to get everything running, but I'm quite new to that stuff, so maybe my solution won't solve your probles.

Anyway. As far as I know, you should use `clang-cl.exe` rather than `clang.exe` with VS. However, building still failed for me in x86 configurations due to some linker problems regarding x86 vs x64 library incompatibilities.

So here's my solution to get both, x64 and x86 configurations, building in VS 2017.

1. Download and install **BOTH** windows clang/llvm installers from http://releases.llvm.org/download.html. You don't have to add them to the path, as we'll explicitly specify the path later.
2. Create a folder with a `CMakeLists.txt`, and open that in VS via the `Open Folder` dialog.
3. In the `CMake` menu, select `Change CMake Settings > CMakeLists.txt`. This will generate a `CMakeSettings.json` containing settings for all build configs.
4. Specify the paths of the x64/x86 cmake compilers in the `cmakeCommandArgs` for all configurations. Mine looks like this:

   ```
   {    // See https://go.microsoft.com//fwlink//?linkid=834763 for more information about this file.

   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "x86-Debug",
           "generator": "Ninja",
           "configurationType": "Debug",
           "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
           "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
           "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
           "cmakeCommandArgs": "-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/windows/LLVM5_x86/bin/clang-cl.exe",
           "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
           "ctestCommandArgs": ""
       },
       {
           "name": "x86-Release",
           "generator": "Ninja",
           "configurationType": "RelWithDebInfo",
           "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
           "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
           "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
           "cmakeCommandArgs": "-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/windows/LLVM5_x86/bin/clang-cl.exe",
           "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
           "ctestCommandArgs": ""
       },
       {
           "name": "x64-Debug",
           "generator": "Ninja",
           "configurationType": "Debug",
           "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64" ],
           "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
           "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
           "cmakeCommandArgs": "-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/windows/LLVM5/bin/clang-cl.exe",
           "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
           "ctestCommandArgs": ""
       },
       {
           "name": "x64-Release",
           "generator": "Ninja",
           "configurationType": "RelWithDebInfo",
           "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64" ],
           "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
           "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
           "cmakeCommandArgs": "-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/windows/LLVM5/bin/clang-cl.exe",
           "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
           "ctestCommandArgs": ""
       }
   ]
   ```

   }

Now you should be able to build both x64 and x86 configurations without errors.

Comment: Thank you for your effort florestan, but I am not sure if you understood my question correctly. I am not asking for a problem with the VS integration. I want to avoid VS where possible and only installed the VS tools for access to the Windows standard libraries and headers.
My problem is that CMake doesn't detect clang or clang-cl as a valid compiler with Ninja as generator.

Comment: OK, I got your question wrong, sorry. Interestingly, even my VS wasn't able to use the correct compiler without specifying it explicitly as stated above. I played a little without VS and I only can confirm your problem :-( CMake seems to completely ignore the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` argument in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but...

In regards to using their current versions, clang, ninja and cmake, if you are building directly in the terminal, you can use this in Powershell:

```bash
cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe" -DCMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/lld-link.exe" -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1
```

You do not need to specify any flags or `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_ID`

##### Tested with:

Clang [16.0.4](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases), Ninja [1.11.1](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases/tag/v1.11.1), Powershell [7.3.4](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.3.4) and CMake [3.26](https://cmake.org/download/)