# How to set property depending on build-type with cmake's command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake

My cmake-based legacy C++ code base contains some specific preprocessor debug macro - let his name be `DEBUG_ATTRIBUTE` - responsible for certain types of debug output. Despite his name, the macro shouldn't be turned on for a standard debug build. For some reason, also all the CMakeLists.txt etc. have to be let alone.

What would be the best way to set the define from cmake's command line, depending on the build-type 'Debug' (cmake creates a Visual Studio 2010 solution)? Can I use generator expressions for this (I suspect, they don't work because of their defining traits)?

Comment: For me it sounds like you should add [toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) for all supported compilers. The possibilities discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake) can all be triggered from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution besides going the long way by writing another script file and injecting this via something like [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html) 
or [`CMAKE_PROJECT_<PROJECT-NAME>_INCLUDE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_PROJECT-NAME_INCLUDE.html).

I've tested the following with CMake's Visual Studio 2015 generator:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT:STRING="-DDEBUG_ATTRIBUTE=SomeValue" ..
```

**References**

- [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT.html)
- [Change default value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and friends in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732209/change-default-value-of-cmake-cxx-flags-debug-and-friends-in-cmake)

Comment: I believe the "-D" inside quotes needs to have a space after it: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT:STRING="-D DEBUG_ATTRIBUTE=SomeValue" ...`