# How to override optimization level flag in modern CMake

Tags: cmake

What's the recommended way of overriding optimization level flags (`-O2`, `-O3` etc. and the MSVC-counterparts with `/`)?

`target_compile_options(mytarget PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELWITHDEBINFO>:/Od>")`

This results in the compiler output:

> cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/O2' with '/Od'

I am happy to use the latest CMake, 3.13.2.

Comment: There isn't a good way.  Someone was asking this on the CMake mailing list and there was some talk about how / why these flags were picked in the first place.  You can however try setting `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>_INIT` or parsing `CMAKE_<LAN>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` and replacing `/O2` with `/Od`.  Or you can manually update the cmake script files that set these values in your installation.

Comment: @Fred Hmm that's a bummer! Do you happen to have the link to that mailing list thread? And since `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO` would already contain `/O2`, which needs to be removed before `/Od` can be added - without touching any of the other compiler flags in the variable - what would be the best way to replace/substitute that specific flag?

Comment: When I use `target_compile_options(mytarget PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELWITHDEBINFO>:/Od>")` I get no warnings and it works as expected.  The `/O2` is not shown in the command line properties for the target.

Comment: Anyways `string(REPLACE "/O2" "/Od" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO})` replaces the flag.

Comment: For anyone looking how to override the default init-Values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32956785/20213170 was very helpful for me.