# Is it possible to compile & link Clang/LLVM using the gold linker?

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, gold-linker

I'm writing a custom pass for LLVM/Clang, and recompiling tends to take a while and use a lot of memory. I've heard that the gold linker (1) takes less time and (2) uses less memory than the standard ld linker.

Is there a way to pass flags into the LLVM/Clang build process and change to the gold linker? As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake/7032021#7032021), I've been attempting to use an override file, but I don't seem to be having a lot of success.

I'll also note that I'm compiling the latest Clang/LLVM build (4.0) using Clang 3.9; I don't mind switching back to GCC if necessary but would rather avoid it.

Comment: Just install the gold package and it will be used instead of ld.

Comment: You might want to consider lld instead of ld, it claims to be faster, too. Not sure how it performances compared to gold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: use a custom linker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867745/cmake-use-a-custom-linker)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Post-4.0 (after commit [rL292047](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/a9134d2526fa011a40656c2b5f8b5124fa38496d)), you should set `LLVM_USE_LINKER` to `gold` like so:

```
cmake ... -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold ...
```

Refer to http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#llvm-specific-variables

---

While you can still use `gold`, these days (October 2021) you should probably use `lld` if it's present in your host toolchain.  If your host toolchain is a clang+llvm distribution from llvm.org, it probably will.  If your host toolchain is from a linux distribution's package manager, it will likely be available but installed as a separate independent package.

```
cmake ... -DLLVM_ENABLE_LLD=ON ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was (and am) stuck with an earlier version of Clang, but this perfectly answers the question. Accepted!