# Cmake cross compiling: finding tools

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cmake, cross-compiling

I am using a standalone toolchain made from the android ndk13b. It works fine, but to find all the tools (linker, archiver etc.) I have a quite verbose section in my toolchain file. **Is there a way to make it more condensed?**

```
SET(COMPILER_PATH   "<path_to_my_llvm_directory>")

SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX aarch64-linux-android-) #In theory should allow to find minor tools like ar and objdump, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7032021/2436175
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   clang.cmd PATH ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++.cmd PATH ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_AR ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}ar.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_RANLIB ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}ranlib.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_LINKER ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}ld.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_NM ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}nm.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objdump.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
find_program(CMAKE_STRIP ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}strip.exe PATHS ${COMPILER_PATH})
```

What didn't work:

- Not explicitly using `find_program` -> It finds some other tools from some other mingw toolchain I have in my path
- Setting [`CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html) to `${COMPILER_PATH}`. It won't even find the compiler at that point. I can workaround that by setting the compiler instead with `SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${COMPILER_PATH}/clang.cmd)` (same for clang++), but it still doesn't find the other tools
- Trying various flags with [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html), especially `ONLY_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`

Note that I found `find_program` to be the only workaround to find the tools, because for example the following won't work:

```
SET(CMAKE_AR ${COMPILER_PATH}/${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}ar.exe
```

(The archive operation will fail and I can see from cmake-gui that the variable is not set).

Comment: `... I can see from cmake-gui that the variable is not set` - `cmake-gui` shows only *cached* variables. You may use `SET(CMAKE_AR ... CACHE PATH "Archiver")`.

Comment: "Is there a way to make it more condensed?" good luck with that. Cmake is a great tool, but the syntax and language behaviour is garbage. It's a real shame (IMHO) that kitware didn't write it in python :(

Comment: @RichardHodges I do have python, but asking all my colleagues to install it just for being able to build our software wouldn't have made our life easier. And making a "complete independent" program out of python is not trivial.

Comment: @Tsyvarev There are exceptions, like if you set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good new is that Android NDK support got a lot easier with the latest CMake 3.7 release. See [Kitware Increases Android Support in CMake 3.7](https://blog.kitware.com/kitware-increases-android-support-in-cmake-3-7/) and [Cross Compiling for Android](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-android).

**Edit:** I have successfully run a test with CMake 3.7 (e.g. installed ADK to root on my Windows PC):

**toolchain.cmake**

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "C:/android-ndk-r13b/platforms/android-24/arch-arm64")
```

And used e.g. the [`Ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/) makefile generator:

```
> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake -G "Ninja" ..
-- Android: Targeting API '24' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
-- Android: Selected GCC toolchain 'aarch64-linux-android-4.9'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.0
```

**Simplified Toolchains in General**

I've made some good experiences with minimal toolchain files and generally - if you want to specify tool paths specifically - using cached variables in the toolchain file.

See [this minimal example](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-using-clang) from CMake's documentation, which would translate in your case into something like:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER <path_to_my_llvm_directory>/clang.cmd)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET aarch64-linux-android)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER <path_to_my_llvm_directory>/clang++.cmd)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET aarch64-linux-android)
```

Note that specifying [`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html) is essential to enable crosscompiling.

**Why specifying `CMAKE_AR` didn't work**

Regarding your `CMAKE_AR` problem please note that CMake itself does use `find_program()` to find `ar.exe`. Since `find_program()` does cache its results, you have to prefill `CMAKE_AR` also as cached variable (see [0013038: cannot set CMAKE_AR when cross-compiling Fortran-only project](http://kwwidgets.org/Bug/view.php?id=13038)).

Comment: The release of CMake 3.7 seems to be synchronized with my question :). Thank you for this very relevant answer, setting those variables the tools are indeed found but I  cannot find a way to convince CMake to use llvm: even this is not sufficient: `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   <full path to the compiler> CACHE PATH "C compiler")`. In all cases, it will try use the gcc/g++ available in the standalone toolchain.

Comment: In the specific workaround I tried, CMake will say `You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER= <my full path>
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= <my full path>`, independently from whatever order I choose for the variable definition.

Comment: @Antonio I've to run some tests with the latest ADK and CMake versions to see if I can reproduce your problem. I'll update my answer accordingly later today. But I'm familiar with the last error message you got: if you change `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` you best start from an empty binary output directory again (it's more or less the same as if you would have changed the generator to be used).

Comment: I had also to revert my CMake installation: my "old" toolchain file won't work anymore!! With CMake 3.6.3 everything is fine. Probably it's better to wait until they polish the 3.7 release.

Comment: Tested on 3.6.3: `Using SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET aarch64-linux-android)` and `SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET aarch64-linux-android)` removes the necessity of the `find_program` commands for all tools! I think for the moment that should be the first part of your answer.

Comment: @Antonio Glad I could help. I've just run a few tests and with setting the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable it did work for me. See my updated answer.