# CMake error: C++ 11 not supported on Mac high sierra

Tags: python, c++, macos, opencv, c++11

I was trying to install opencv for python using [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/#comment-449798). After running the Cmake command, it exited with errors stating `C++11 is not supported` Although I have Xcode installed. I Also tried forcing Cmake to use C++ 11 using `$ set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` (because my Cmake version is 3.10.2), but I got this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD'
```

Moreover, I tried installing gcc to check if my system supports the C++ 11 compiler through [this link](https://github.com/cmangos/issues/wiki/Getting-a-C--11-compiler-on-Mac-OS-X), where again I ran into terminal errors stating `./fixincludes: No such file or directory` after running `$ make install` . What should I do?

Comment: Can you run gcc --version in your terminal? what's the version number?

Comment: @StefanoBuora I think it is 4.2.1 according to the first line, or am I reading it wrong?
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: The version sounds good, I've got the same with the latest Xcode version installed

Comment: gcc 4.2 is *way* older than C++11. Of course that does not work.

Comment: If you have xcode you probably have a recent version of clang which should support C++11, 14 and probably even 17. Installing gcc isn't a good idea, but if you do do that, pick a version that isn't ancient.

Comment: You are right, I'm using CLang (not gcc) in my projects and it works nicely with C++11 constructs

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html, sais that, if you want to use C++11 constructs, it should be gcc 4.8 or greater

Comment: I think you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake

Comment: @juanchopanza I have Xcode installed, so why do I get "C++ 11 not supported" with Cmake?

Comment: @Ghazal.S No idea. What does `c++ --version` give you in the command line?

Comment: @StefanoBuora Thanks. So now I should install gcc 4.8 or higher. As I mentioned I went through this tutorial https://github.com/cmangos/issues/wiki/Getting-a-C--11-compiler-on-Mac-OS-X, but I got stuck after getting this error ./fixincludes: No such file or directory . What should I do now?

Comment: At which step of the wiki page have you got the error?

Comment: @Ghazal.S From the second comment, you already have a recent version of clang++. Unless OpenCV requires that you install gcc, which I seriously doubt, don't do it. Also, gcc 4.8 is ancient anyway. It would make no sense to install that. Better look up how to build opencv on mac OS.

Comment: @StefanoBuora I got it after step 9 (make install)

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I guess so. I also did a bit of searching and it turns out I don't have any gcc installed (according to my second comment) unlike the latest version of clang ++.  Ok I won't install gcc, but I know some part of my cmake for opencv needs c++ 11, and that's where I thought I should install gcc to support it.

Comment: why didn't you use homebrew (you installed it in your tutorial) for installing GCC? it installs the last version of GCC by default.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani Hello Parham! (We met on Noor's Birthday :D) I have already installed homebrew, but I don't know how to use it for installing gcc...could you please help me?
I also think my whole problem is that I can't enable c++ on cmake. I tried running this command in the terminal: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) but it doesn't work out as I get the abovementioned error.(syntax error near unexpected token `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD')

Comment: Hello :D. for installing GCC using homebrew use `brew install gcc`. after installing GCC I think your problem must be solved.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work as well

Comment: Homebrew installation failed or GCC installed successfully and cmake failed again?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani GCC installed successfully and cmake failed again due to the same error (c++ 11 not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Adrian has a more recent blog post on [compiling OpenCV for the macOS](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/29/macos-for-deep-learning-with-python-tensorflow-and-keras/).  The instructions work both for 3.3.0 and 3.3.1.

Comment: Thanks, I executed the steps as this tutorial suggested again but the same issue occurred as well.

Answer (score 0):

First open python by `python2` or `python3` command in terminal after type `import cv2` and everything is right now.