# Mixed Clang and GCC

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang

Are there any good reference projects that mix Clang and GCC?

My use case here is compiling OpenMP code with GCC and everything else with Clang. Added bonus if CMAKE supported this somehow.

Comment: This might give you some ideas, though it's not your exact use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake

Comment: So have a whitelist of files to use GCC on, tell cmake to only build object files; tell cmake to link those in on the clang side?