# Is there a cmake compile feature for c++17's charconv?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I have written some code that make use c++17's [charconv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/charconv), that I can compile just fine with g++ 9. Even though I have set the std to c++17 in my CMakeLists.txt, cmake insists on using c++ 7.5, which does not support charconv.

How do I tell cmake that I need a compiler that supports charconv ?
I see no switch in CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

file(GLOB CLIENT_SRC "srcs/*.cpp")
include_directories("includes")

add_executable(client ${CLIENT_SRC})

set_target_properties(client PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "distff-client")

target_compile_features(client PUBLIC cxx_std_17 )
```

Comment: if on linux did you try to use update alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031126/switching-between-gcc-and-clang-llvm-using-cmake/12843988#12843988

Comment: Given your statement that CMake is only using C++  7.5, this suggests you have two versions of c++ installed.  Version 7.5 and 9.   Unless you specify the compiler to use via a toolchain file, or some other method (like setting CXX environment variable indicated below), CMake will typically use the first one it finds in the path.  If target_compile_features does not find the desired feature, it won't search for another version of C++ it will just compile with what it has and ideally give a warning or error.  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a cmake guy... and I don't really understand cmake's approach to compile features here. But in C++ in general, we now use feature-test macros to detect the presence of features. You're looking specifically for [`__cpp_lib_to_chars`](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations#__cpp_lib_to_chars).

I think you want to require compilation of this program:

```
#if __has_include(<version>)
#  include <version>
#elif __has_include(<charconv>)
#  include <charconv>
#else
#  error "neither <version> nor <charconv> available to test"
#endif

#ifndef __cpp_lib_to_chars
#  error "tochars not implemented"
#endif
```

Which can probably be generalized to something you can `configure_file()` for an arbitrary library feature (just pull out the header name and the macro name, and probably also check for the macro having the minimum required value).

Either way, if you [`try_compile()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html#try-compiling-source-files) the resultant source file, you could probably get the behavior you want?

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of try_compile(). How would you use it to pick a compiler ? I believe there's no way to get a list of installed compilers. The best I can do is ask the user the specify a different compiler.

Comment: @DontBreakAlex Pick a compiler? I thought you pick the compiler.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I believe to point of target_compile_features() is to allow cmake to pick a compiler that supports them. If think I have to use autoconf if this is not the case, I have not idea what I'm doing.

Comment: I think that CMake is not really extending `target_compile_features` (no C++17).
You can see them defined here (for C++): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html

Answer (score 0):

Not a CMAKE expert, but the easiest would be to set the **CXX** environment variable. Like so:

```
export CXX="/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9"
```

see more at [How to specify a compiler in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933732/how-to-specify-a-compiler-in-cmake/45934279)