# Installing only clang and cmake, CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clang

I'm trying to use clang with CMake. Here's my Dockerfile. You can see that I did not install build-essentials, only clang, because I dont want GNU compilers to be made default.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

WORKDIR /home/project

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update\
    && apt-get install -y clang wget

RUN wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.18.0-rc2/cmake-3.18.0-rc2-Linux-x86_64.sh && ls

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/cmake \
&& chmod +x cmake-3.18.0-rc2-Linux-x86_64.sh \
&& ./cmake-3.18.0-rc2-Linux-x86_64.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr/local/cmake

ENV PATH="/usr/local/cmake/bin:${PATH}"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project(libsmoltcp_cpp LANGUAGES CXX)
```

Here's what I get when running `cmake .`:

```
root@275dbeaae123:/home/project# cmake .
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/project/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

In `update-alternatives` there's just clang:

```
root@275dbeaae123:/home/project# update-alternatives --config cc
There is only one alternative in link group cc (providing /usr/bin/cc): /usr/bin/clang
Nothing to configure.
```

Comment: `sudo apt install make` ?

Comment: clang alone also won't work. You'd need libc++. Better to tell cmake what to use when you invoke cmake, than to do any of this. You're trying to sidestep cmake's big advantage.

Comment: @sweenish the two options I have are: using an override file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7032021/6655884 which does not look nice, and updating the alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12843988/6655884 which is not scriptable

Comment: @LucasZanella: What about **fixing the first error message** `CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles"`? It is noted in your title and completely **unrelated** to clang. Please, in the question post concentrate on a **single problem**. And make sure you have no other problems, especially ones which could affect on the original one. (Without `make` as a build utility checking the compiler has no sense).

Comment: "Which does not look nice" is a really poor excuse. If you're going to ignore cmake's biggest strength, it's not going to be elegant. Personally, I alias the cmake command on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your CMake configuration is generating Makefiles that should be run with `make` but it isn't installed.
Install make.

The second issue could be you have configured C language:

```
update-alternatives --config cc
```

And may need to configure C++ language:

```
update-alternatives --set g++ /usr/bin/clang
```